# Read record from XML file in SQL Server Table

Tags: sql-server

I have xml statement for which I want value for `AlertString` in table format:

```
<ArrayOfAlertInfo xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <AlertInfo>
       <AlertString xmlns="http://www.example.org/abc/v1_0">Test 1</AlertString>
       <AlertString xmlns="http://www.example.org/abc/v1_0">Test 2</AlertString>
       <AlertString xmlns="http://www.example.org/abc/v1_0">Test 3</AlertString>
       <AlertTime xmlns="http://www.example.org/abc/v1_0">1466227822997</AlertTime>
   </AlertInfo>
</ArrayOfAlertInfo>
```

Desired result wanted:

```
Test 1 . Test 2 . Test 3
```

Comment: I tried using 'Select d.value('.','Varchar(2000)') as AlertString    From @AlertInfo.nodes ('ArrayOfAlertInfo') as a(b)     Cross apply b.nodes('AlertInfo')as c(d)'

but i am getting result as 'Test 1Test 2Test 31466227822997'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<ArrayOfAlertInfo xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <AlertInfo>
       <AlertString xmlns="http://www.example.org/abc/v1_0">Test 1</AlertString>
       <AlertString xmlns="http://www.example.org/abc/v1_0">Test 2</AlertString>
       <AlertString xmlns="http://www.example.org/abc/v1_0">Test 3</AlertString>
       <AlertTime xmlns="http://www.example.org/abc/v1_0">1466227822997</AlertTime>
   </AlertInfo>
</ArrayOfAlertInfo>'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.example.org/abc/v1_0' AS ns)
SELECT 
    XC.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM 
    @input.nodes('/ArrayOfAlertInfo/AlertInfo/ns:AlertString') AS XT(XC)
```

Gives me an output of:

[image]

Comment: This is helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

This artical can help you.
[Reading XML File Using T-SQL](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/13/sql-server-simple-example-of-reading-xml-file-using-t-sql/)

Comment: If the xml was with out the namespace , then this would help.